# What causes the problem in Protractor = Failed: script timeout error

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor, e2e-testing

Here is my code, it opens the page I want, input `username` and `password`, click the `login` button and get a wrong error or open the main page but after that nothing happens.

```
it('Wrong id pass input causes error', async () => {
        page = new AppPage();
        page.navigateTo();
        $("#exampleInput1").sendKeys("aaa")
        $("#exampleInput2").sendKeys("bbb")
        $("button").click();
        let isToastWarningPresent = await $("div#toast-container>.toast-warning").isDisplayed()
        expect(isToastWarningPresent)
        })

    it('Right id pass input redirect you to mainpage', async () => {
        page = new AppPage();
        page.navigateTo();
        $("#exampleInput1").sendKeys(username)
        $("#exampleInput2").sendKeys(password)
        $("button").click();
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(expectedUrl)
    })
```

My expects are broken. An expect need to return `true` or `false` but after waiting a couple of seconds it says:

```
Failed: script timeout
    (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.82)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c50024bab004e48d2b1b083cdbdac579-refs/branch-heads/4389@{#294}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19041 x86_64)
```

I try to rise `allScriptsTimeout` to 110000 but in that time the error changes to :

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Think that it happens because of `block-ui` but when I try in another `block-ui` nothing bad happens.

Comment: From my experience, even if the page is displayed well in the browser, Protractor "waits" from all async tasks/angular rendering to be resolved. To help you more, you should post the relevant code of your component/child components to reproduce the issue.

Comment: do research about protractor's `waitForAngularEnabled`

Comment: waitForAngularEnabled solved my problem thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); solved my problem. Thanks.